# Reduce execution time c# algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I'm solving [Kattis' bokforing](http://open.kattis.com/problems/bokforing) problem and one of the test cases fails due to execution time being too long (> 2 sec). Can anyone give me any advice on how I can improve?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        /* Inputs 
            3 5
            SET 1 7
            PRINT 1
            PRINT 2
            RESTART 33
            PRINT 1
         */
        string first = Console.ReadLine();
        int N = Convert.ToInt32(first.Split(" ")[0]);
        int Q = Convert.ToInt32(first.Split(" ")[1]);

        int[] Accounts = new int[N];
        string[] Operations = new string[Q];

        for (int i = 0; i < Operations.Length; i++)
        {
            Operations[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Operations.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] op = Operations[i].Split(" ");
            string operation = op[0];

            int accountId = 0;
            int ammont = 0;

            if (operation == "SET")
            {
                accountId = Convert.ToInt32(op[1]);
                ammont = Convert.ToInt16(op[2]);
                Accounts[accountId - 1] = ammont;
            }
            if (operation == "PRINT")
            {
                accountId = Convert.ToInt32(op[1]);
                Console.WriteLine(Accounts[accountId - 1]);
            }
            if (operation == "RESTART")
            {
                ammont = Convert.ToInt16(op[1]);
                for (int j = 0; j <= N - 1; j++)
                {
                    Accounts[j] = ammont;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you measure time? -- Most of it is likely to be fixed startup cost.

Comment: It will be irrelevant but _operation_ has just one value for loop. Use  _else if_ to test for the different cases.

Comment: using a Stopwatch and measuring just the inner loop give a total execution time of less than 2 milliseconds. Something is not quite right in how do you measure time.

Comment: No way this takes 2 seconds to complete. There is _nothing_ computationally intensive, or massive nested loops here.

Comment: Note that the split operation requires a character and not a string, like `.Split(' ')`

Comment: @JohnAlexiou not with NetCore. Split accepts also a single string

Comment: other than calling `.Split()` multiple times, I don't see any other improvements. When I run this using `Console.SetIn()` to redirect input from string, it completes in `0.0015287 seconds`.

Comment: These code is tested by kattis [https://open.kattis.com/], more precisely the problem is https://open.kattis.com/problems/bokforing. I think that they perform other tests with different amounts of data  and the execution gets more than 2 sec.

Comment: @MarjoZotaj please add the info about kattis to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I copied recommended IO classes from [FAQ](https://open.kattis.com/help/csharp#faq_lang) to the solution, removed double loop (there is no need to loop twice - reading inputs first and then processing them) and then the main trick was to use `Dictionary` instead of array so there is no need to manually clear it/set amount to all items in it every time:

```cs
var scanner = new Scanner();

using(var writer = new BufferedStdoutWriter())
{
    var N = scanner.NextInt();
    var Q = scanner.NextInt();

    var amount = 0;
    var Accounts = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    for (var i = 0; i < Q; i++)
    {
        var s = scanner.Next();
        var accountId = 0;

        if (s == "SET")
        {
            accountId = scanner.NextInt();
            Accounts[accountId] = scanner.NextInt();
        }
        else if (s == "PRINT")
        {
            accountId = scanner.NextInt();

            if (!Accounts.TryGetValue(accountId, out var value))
            {
                value = amount;
            }

            writer.WriteLine(value);
        }
        else if (s == "RESTART")
        {
            amount = scanner.NextInt();
            Accounts = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        }
    }
}
```